# Parameterization of a spherical spiral

Tags: parametrization, spherical-geometry

For a spherical spiral curve, parametric representation is given as:

$x=r \sin(t) \cos(ct)$, $y=r \sin(t) \sin(ct)$, $z=r \cos(t)$ with $t=[0,\pi]$ and $c$ a constant.

How can I translate this to a surface parameterization of a 3D spherical spiral, having its own minor radius ?

The surface should look like something similar to this:   [Spherical Helix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcZFQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Converting your original equation into a vector gets 
$$\overrightarrow C=\langle r\sin(t)\cos(ct) , r\sin(t)\sin(ct), r\cos(t)\rangle$$
Then, the tangent vector is
$$\overrightarrow T=\langle r\cos(t)\cos(ct)-rc\sin(t)\sin(ct) , r\cos(t)\sin(ct)+rc\sin(t)\cos(ct), -r\sin(t)\rangle$$
A normal vector is
$$\overrightarrow N=\langle r\cos(t)\sin(ct)+rc\sin(t)\cos(ct) , rc\sin(t)\sin(ct)-r\cos(t)\cos(ct), 0\rangle$$
Then the binormal vector is the cross product which is
$$\overrightarrow B=\langle-r^2 \cos(t) \cos(c t) \sin(t) + c r^2 \sin^2(t) \sin(c t), -c r^2 \cos(c t) \sin^2(t) - r^2 \cos(t) \sin(t) \sin(c t), -r^2 \cos^2(t) \cos^2(c t) - c^2 r^2 \cos^2(c t) \sin^2(t) - r^2 \cos^2(t) \sin^2(c t) - c^2 r^2 \sin^2(t) \sin^2(c t)\rangle$$
(This is getting out of hand quickly)
Using $u$ as the second parameter, we get the final equation for the helix is $$\overrightarrow C+\frac{\overrightarrow N}{\|\overrightarrow N\|} R\cos(u)+\frac{\overrightarrow B}{\|\overrightarrow B\|} R\sin(u)$$ 
which I do not have the guts to write out fully.

Comment: Thanks ! If we are using normal and binormal vectors of the curve, shouldn't we normalize them first ? 

Side note: according to the matlab plot, the proposed solution is wrong

Comment: Oh, yes they should be normalized. Because they are not _the_ normal and binormal, I'll edit it so that they are normalized only in the final solution

Comment: Calculations get pretty messy, especially for the binormal vector and its magnitude. Don't you think that there should be an easier way to solve this issue e.g. by using arc length parameterization ?